# xUbuntu Default desktop Icons do not display?

Tags: icons

Even though I have the default icons set to display in Settings, they do not display. See the image below. Ideas????

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Solved!!

Went to "Settings Manager" then "Desktop" then "Icons" and under the "Appearance" dropdown menu picked "File/launcher icons," and then like magic..... the desktop icons displayed!!!!    I am a happy camper.